# How to select the optimal probability threshold for classifiers in R?

Tags: r, classification, svm, threshold

I am creating a binary classifier in R, but I don't know what probability threshold to select for class separation.
The code is as follows:

```
tune.out <-
    tune(svm, X0 ~ ., 
         data = data.frame(y = as.vector(class_train), model_train),
         kernel = "polynomial", ranges = list(cost = c(0.001,0.01,0.1, 1,5,10,100)))
  
  bestmod <-
    tune.out$best.model
  
  Index <-
    order(class_train, decreasing = FALSE)
  
  
  SVMfit_Var <-
    svm(model_train[Index, ], class_train[Index, ],
        type= "eps-regression",kernel = "polynomial", cost = bestmod$cost, gamma=bestmod$gamma, epsilon = bestmod$epsilon, scale=F)
  
  
  preds1 <-
    predict(SVMfit_Var, Xtest, probability = TRUE)
  preds1 <-
    attr(preds1, "probabilities")[,1]
  
  prediction <- predict(SVMfit_Var, model_valid, probability = T)
  xtab <- table(t(class_valid), prediction)
  inf.pred <- rep(0, dim(model_valid)[1])
  inf.pred[prediction > 0.5] = 1
  
  performance <- Conf(table(inf.pred, t(class_valid)))
```

Right now I have a threshold of 0.5. The problem is that the calculated probabilities are all 0.1.

[image]

The values displayed are 0.1, although there seem to be decimals that are not displayed.
In this case, the index values 1-145 are class 0, and 145-180 class 1.

How can I set an optimal threshold for the classifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to base the threshold on the proportion of positive classes seen in your training data. For example, if 20% of cases in your training data have a positive class, then you could pick the same proportion of cases in your test data, classifying the 20% with the highest probabilities as positive.

Whether this approach is appropriate or not really depends on your classification problem. The model can tell you the probability of a case being positive or negative - how you decide to use those probabilities to make a classification is a question to be considered outside of the modelling, and really depends on the cost of mis-classifying in your particular case.